# Is this a badly designed API?

Tags: javascript, python, api

I'm trying to use the geni.com APIs, but I'm confused about the response I'm getting.

Specifically this one: **`https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help/api?path=user%2Fmanaged-profiles&version=1`**

After authorising myself with my API key (successfully), the response I am getting depends on what I use to make the call.

If I use Python as follows, then I get a fully formed HTML document

```
Python snippet
URLManagedProfiles = "https://www.geni.com/api/user/managed-profiles"
r = requests.get(URLManagedProfiles)
```

If I goto my web browser, and log in to geni.com and then paste this URL into the browser bar, I get a pure json list of GUIDs and names, which is what I want.

```
Browser address bar
https://www.geni.com/api/user/managed-profiles

{
results: [
{
guid: "6000000003440360004",
name: "xxxxx"
},
{
guid: "6000000004787958755",
name: "xxxxx"
},
{
guid: "6000000004828562356",
name: "xxxxx"
},
{
guid: "6000000004823232333",
etc
```

Now, the documentation on the website seems to suggest I should use javascript .... but I have almost no exposure to that.

Question:

1. Is this API constructed in some weird way? I know we can't see what's behind it, but the way it behaves is just... unexpected.
2. Am I being overly optimistic hoping to be able to use the APIs through Python?

Comment: If it’s a rest api, you should be able to use it with any language. You have to give an example of the api response.

Comment: OK, added a sample of the broswer's response.

Comment: How do you perform authentication in your Python code?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You're asking for a design review, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3840170 Well, that is probably the problem. It doesn;t feel right that I call one API, and get tokens and everything, but don;t have to use them to make further post-login calls.

But the API documentation doesn't explain how to do it. So... is this a weirdly designed API?

Answer (score 2):

> After authorising myself with my API key (successfully)

```
URLManagedProfiles = "https://www.geni.com/api/user/managed-profiles"
r = requests.get(URLManagedProfiles)
```

There's no authentication here.  You're getting the HTML for the login page.

Comment: But I'm not. 

Using Chrome, I head over to geni.com. Login successfully. Now open a new tab, or simply replace the URL with this: https://www.geni.com/api/user/managed-profiles and I get a pure JSON response.

Comment: Your Python code and your web browser do not share authentication information.  As far as the API is concerned, you are not logged in when you make your request with that Python code. You need to authenticate yourself in your Python code.

Comment: Agreed, that is intuitively correct to me. But the API as documented, makes no provision for this. Which is why I'm struggling to understand how it;s supposed to work in a non-javascript approach.

Comment: It's not clearly documented, but you can see from the PHP example that you need to add an `access_token` query string parameter to authenticate requests: https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help/oauth_server_side?version=1